# Stdapi commands not showing in meterpreter session

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I created a android payload with public IP (`android/meterpreter/reverse_https`).
The stdapi commands(`ls`,`cd`,`webcam_snap` etc) are showing when the victim is in the same network.

But when I try to connect over the Internet( i.e. victim is in a different network) using a public IP, the `stdapi` commands do not show in the meterpreter session.

Further, the meterpreter session is quite unstable, and displays errors after sometime:

> meterpreter session is not valid and will be closed

Answer (score 0):

With metepreter sessions, you need to make sure you migrate to a running application. So for example, when obtaining a session for Windows you would migrate to explorer.exe

If you want to migrate, list the running applications with `ps` and then it will give you the list. After that, you type `migrate [application PID]` without the brackets. This should stop your `meterpreter session is not valid and will be closed` situation.

The `stdapi` will only be given and only load if the module is handing you administrative rights.

Comment: But the stdapi commands are visible and working when using the payload in a same network device, and not in a different network. So i guess its not an admin rights issue, is it?

Comment: And the  "meterpreter session is not valid and will be closed" error also occurs in different network payload(over WAN), not in the same network(over LAN).